# Calculating Dirichlet Integral in Python

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I'm trying to calculate the integral

```
sin(x)/x , x = [0,inf]
```

I do the following :

```py
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

t = float("inf")
def integrand(x):
    return (math.sin(x))/x
ans, err = quad(integrand, 0, t)

print(ans)
```

However I get the wrong answer:
It should be Pi/2 and the answer from Python is 2.247.

Do you know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating a difficult integral -- the Dirichlet integral isn't even defined unless you use very specific definitions of the integral. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html the function you're using -- `quad`, is for `General purpose integration`. Take into account that it's using an approximation algorithm.

Did you look at the warning? My output shows:

```
/Users/jdong/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:364: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
```

... and my error is `3.2903230524472544`. So technically PI/2 is within the error bounds.

Also, you're calculating to infinity, where it's not really necessary. The sinc function tends to zero moderately quickly, so you can simply do `quad(integrand,0,100)` and get a decent result. Note that as you increase the limit however, you will need to increase the number of subdivisions used by quad. e.g. `quad(integrand,0,100000,limit=10000)`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it's work. Could you explain this sentence please:"The sinc function tends to zero moderately quickly, so you can simply do quad(integrand,0,100) and get a decent result"

Comment: Sure, if you take a look at a graph of sinc https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Si_sinc.svg/670px-Si_sinc.svg.png you can see as x goes to infinity, the y values get smaller in magnitude. That is, the integral of sinc from 1000 to 2000 is small, and the integral of sinc from 2000 to 3000 is even smaller. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sinc you can see that the integral slowly converges.